# Design pattern for creating private 1:1 auction scenarios in corda

Tags: corda

Auctions are common in many of the trade scenarios  . 
For example , an invoice-market place would like to do auctioning of invoices with lenders . But the communication between marketplace and each of the lenders is one to one . Ie marketplace contacts , lender-1  and lender-2 privately  & each of the lenders submit their secret bids separately  to market-place.

But from marketplace point of view, market-place is kind of starting auction   communication in parallel with the potential bidders.

One way to achieve this might be to  send "one to one" flows in corda and then collate the results together .

Is there a better way than the above to achieve such scenarios ? So that the market-place could avoid collating results from separate flows .

Answer (score 0):

So generally with cordapps you want to think about 3 things primarily.

1. what are the objects I'm interested in managing or representing using my cordapp (what are the corda state objects / class definitions)
2. What are the things that can be done with those objects? (corda contracts and commands)
3. what are the business processes that control the way the objects change. (corda flows).

There's actually a sample cordapp around auctions that you can take a look at online, here's the example in java, but it's also around in kotlin as well.

https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Advanced/auction-cordapp